# Default ACL to backup another user's home directory

Tags: ansible, access-control-list, setfacl

I have written a script to backup our servers.
It runs as the "backup" user on multiple Oracle Linux 7/8/9 systems and has to backup other users homes directories, among other things, using restic.
I deployed this script using Ansible and setup the ACL on the directories to backup with Ansible as well.

This is the relevant part that sets the correct ACL on the directories I want to backup up:

```
    - name: give read/exec access to backup user on all folders to backup
      ansible.posix.acl:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        entry: "u:{{ backup_user }}:rX"
        state: present
        recursive: true
      with_items:
        - "{{ paths_to_back_up }}"
    - name: give default read/exec access to backup user on all folders to backup
      ansible.posix.acl:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        entry: "d:u:{{ backup_user }}:rX"
        state: present
        recursive: true
      with_items:
        - "{{ paths_to_back_up }}"
    - name: set default mask on all folders to backup
      ansible.posix.acl:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        etype: mask
        permissions: "rX"
        state: present
        recursive: true
      with_items:
        - "{{ paths_to_back_up }}"
```

Every once in a while, the .bashrc file or the .config folder will not be readable by the backup user.
It seems that the mode of those file changes to 600 which means that the permissions of the 'backup' user are limited to 0.

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I haven't found what it is and it is driving me mad.